# Multiprocessing a simple Python foreach?

Tags: python

Starting learn python and i'm searching to increase the speed execution for the loop START/END which are commented. Do you think multiprocessing are the best solution or there another way for increasing the performance cause only 10% of CPU are used

```py
def merge_csv(names):
        n = 0
        while n < len(names[0]):
            _, filename["%s" %n] = os.path.split(names[0][n])
            temp_data["%s" %n] = pandas.read_csv(open(names[0][n]), sep=',|;')
        
            data["%s" %n] = pandas.DataFrame(temp_data["%s" %n])
            data["%s" %n].insert(1, "oround", 1)
            data["%s" %n].insert(3, "pround", 1)
            
            for i in range(len(data["%s" %n].mz)):
                data["%s" %n].iloc[i,1]=round(data["%s" %n].iloc[i,0],2)
                data["%s" %n].iloc[i,3]=round(data["%s" %n].iloc[i,2],1)

            liste = list(zip(data["%s" %n]["oround"], data["%s" %n]["pround"]))
            listeall.extend(liste)
            n = n+1
        
        liste2 = list(set([u for u in listeall]))
        
        merged = pandas.DataFrame(liste2)
        colonnes = ["o", "oround", "p", "pround", "td", "u", "counts"]
        m = 0
        j = 0
        for j in range(len(names[0])):
                name_data = os.path.basename(names[0][j])
                for m in range(len(colonnes)):
                    colm = colonnes[m] + name_data
                    merged.insert(len(colonnes)*j+2+m, colm, 0)
         
       """
       START
        p = 0
        n = 0
        x=0
        y=0
        for n in range(len(names[0])):
            for p in range(len(liste2)):
                couple = liste2[p]
                resultmz = data["%s" %n]["oround"].isin([couple[0]])
                listemz = list(resultmz[resultmz == True].index)
                resultrt = data["%s" %n]["pround"].isin([couple[1]])
                listert = list(resultrt[resultrt == True].index)
                if len(listemz)>0 and len(listert)>0:
                    for x in range(len(listemz)) :
                        for y in range(len(listert)) :
                            if listemz[x] == listert[y]:
                                for k in range(7):
                                    merged.iloc[p,7*n+2+k] = data["%s" %n].iloc[int(listemz[x]),k]
        END
        """          
        csvmerged = results.to_csv('merged.csv')
        
        print(csvmerged)             
        return merged
```

I know how to start single threads in Python but I don't know how to "collect" the results.

What's the easiest way to parallelize this loop?

```
for n in range(len(names[0])):
```

Code after cmbfast suggestion:

```py
def merge_file_CCS(names):
        n = 0
        while n < len(names[0]):
            _, filename["%s" %n] = os.path.split(names[0][n])
            temp_data["%s" %n] = pandas.read_csv(open(names[0][n]), sep=',|;')
        
            data["%s" %n] = pandas.DataFrame(temp_data["%s" %n])
            data["%s" %n].insert(1, "oround", 1)
            data["%s" %n].insert(3, "pround", 1)
            
            for i in range(len(data["%s" %n].mz)):
                data["%s" %n].iloc[i,1]=round(data["%s" %n].iloc[i,0],2)
                data["%s" %n].iloc[i,3]=round(data["%s" %n].iloc[i,2],1)
            
            liste = list(zip(data["%s" %n]["oround"], data["%s" %n]["pround"]))
            listeall.extend(liste)
            print("CSV read in --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
            n = n+1
            
        print("All CSV read in --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

        liste2 = list(set([u for u in listeall]))
        
        merged = pandas.DataFrame(liste2)
        colonnes = ["o", "oround", "p", "pround", "td", "u", "counts"]
        m = 0
        j = 0
        for j in range(len(names[0])):
                name_data = os.path.basename(names[0][j])
                for m in range(len(colonnes)):
                    colm = colonnes[m] + name_data
                    merged.insert(len(colonnes)*j+2+m, colm, 0)
        
        pools = Pool(num_pool)
        results = []
        for result in pools.imap(pool_merge, names):
            results.append(result)
        pools.close()
        pools.join()
                    
        csvmerged = merged.to_csv('merged.csv')
        
        print(csvmerged)             
        return merged

def pool_merge(n):
        p = 0
        x = 0
        y = 0
        for p in range(len(liste2)):
            couple = liste2[p]
            resultmz = data["%s" %n]["oround"].isin([couple[0]])
            listemz = list(resultmz[resultmz == True].index)
            resultrt = data["%s" %n]["pround"].isin([couple[1]])
            listert = list(resultrt[resultrt == True].index)
            if len(listemz)>0 and len(listert)>0:
                for x in range(len(listemz)) :
                    for y in range(len(listert)) :
                        if listemz[x] == listert[y]:
                            for k in range(7):
                                merged.iloc[p,7*n+2+k] = data["%s" %n].iloc[int(listemz[x]),k]
```

but it give me the error

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'pool_merge' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Comment: Youre on the right track. Few problems however, for eg, `pool_merge` is not returning anything. Also looks like `n` and `liste2` are arguments of `pool_merge`, while youre just giving `n`. And finally `pools.imap(pool_merge, names)` is giving `names` to `pool_merge` function. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pool`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count


num_pool = cpu_count()//2
pools = Pool(num_pool)
results = []
for result in pools.imap(merge_csv, names):
    results.append(result)
pools.close()
pools.join()
```

`names` is a list of names passed to your function `merge_csv`. You can concat your final results using `pd.concat(results)`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I'm trying to multiprocessing only the loop commented with START/END comment, because i have to load all my csv before doing that loop for merge everything on final file. I guess your solution are for multiprocessing the entire function merge_csv no?

Comment: yes. In that case, you could move your commented part outside the function `merge_csv` as a new function, say `new_func` with the arguments `x`.  Then use the above multiprocessing code with your `new_func`.

Comment: I did but got the error AttributeError: Can't get attribute, i have put more details in initial post. I'm missing something?